Multiple browser windows not working independently
I have users complained that every time they are on my website trying to view data/graphs and if they want to multitask by having multiple browser windows, then they cannot use multiple windows.
If they are processing a request on one browser window then the second window doesn't load until the first window loads completely. The second window will keep showing ajax loading sign until first one loads completely. Why is that? My thinking was each window request should be independent of the other. Shouldn't be any blocking.
Any suggestions?

It may well be how many threads and processes that IIS has been setup for.  And it not clear if session() is being used to save the same values for each page (that suggests each page would and could lock session forcing the other page to wait). Each page should in theory be able to grab + use another processor thread, but one does not want to confuse a threading model vs that of a parallel processing model, they are two different things. So, if the server has no extra threads, then indeed, users will wait, and that includes one user with 2 pages open.  How many cores on the server?

6 virtual processors

Well, IIS 7 is rather old, and tends to run on servers that did not even support NUMA (multiple processors accessing memory at the same time).  As noted, it's possible a lot of session() values are being used, and that can cause blocking.  And virtual processors kind of does not matter if you don't have multiple cores. Remember, I can run IIS on a single core computer. So, as I stated, a threading model is NOT the same as parallel processing model.  How heavy is session() used for that page? I would do some testing on your dev computer - see if the same issue exists. I think IIS7 is the issue

Sorry, it is IIS 10, Windows Server 2016

Ok, then a "guess" would be that both of the pages use session[] to persit values, and you using SQL server based session. That means that one page when it sets some values into session, it can wind up blocking the other page.  So, consider using ViewState in place of session. In other words, you can freely pass some values to the given web page using session, but on page load move the values into ViewState (which is per page). Since both pages may well be saving into the SAME session values, then blocking can occur. Other ideas: set app-pool to run only x64 bits if not already.

Please try to create a minimal sample to reproduce the issue, and that can help you narrow down the culprit.

I think it is related to max html request that can be sent by browser https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser
